# IloCplex.solve() failing to satisfy all constraints, even though solve() method returns true

Tags: java, cplex

I've started to fiddle with the CPLEX Java API just recently and all was looking fine until the LP were not solved althgough it said they were...

I have the following LP:

```
IloModel  {
IloMinimize  : (0.0*x0101 + 9.0*x0102 + 74.0*x0103 + 6.0*x0104 + 47.0*x0105 + 72.0*x0106 + 15.0*x0107 + 96.0*x0108 + 76.0*x0109 + 33.0*x0110 + 95.0*x0201 + 0.0*x0202 + 69.0*x0203 + 3.0*x0204 + 84.0*x0205 + 39.0*x0206 + 7.0*x0207 + 3.0*x0208 + 33.0*x0209 + 1.0*x0210 + 60.0*x0301 + 49.0*x0302 + 0.0*x0303 + 81.0*x0304 + 43.0*x0305 + 16.0*x0306 + 11.0*x0307 + 15.0*x0308 + 23.0*x0309 + 9.0*x0310 + 15.0*x0401 + 77.0*x0402 + 2.0*x0403 + 0.0*x0404 + 67.0*x0405 + 22.0*x0406 + 93.0*x0407 + 72.0*x0408 + 97.0*x0409 + 84.0*x0410 + 67.0*x0501 + 29.0*x0502 + 62.0*x0503 + 64.0*x0504 + 0.0*x0505 + 56.0*x0506 + 87.0*x0507 + 29.0*x0508 + 12.0*x0509 + 92.0*x0510 + 13.0*x0601 + 93.0*x0602 + 22.0*x0603 + 25.0*x0604 + 60.0*x0605 + 0.0*x0606 + 32.0*x0607 + 42.0*x0608 + 61.0*x0609 + 4.0*x0610 + 7.0*x0701 + 24.0*x0702 + 12.0*x0703 + 86.0*x0704 + 27.0*x0705 + 52.0*x0706 + 0.0*x0707 + 71.0*x0708 + 12.0*x0709 + 56.0*x0710 + 97.0*x0801 + 69.0*x0802 + 45.0*x0803 + 10.0*x0804 + 85.0*x0805 + 25.0*x0806 + 72.0*x0807 + 0.0*x0808 + 38.0*x0809 + 78.0*x0810 + 23.0*x0901 + 97.0*x0902 + 12.0*x0903 + 81.0*x0904 + 56.0*x0905 + 99.0*x0906 + 71.0*x0907 + 71.0*x0908 + 0.0*x0909 + 35.0*x0910 + 56.0*x1001 + 2.0*x1002 + 60.0*x1003 + 77.0*x1004 + 96.0*x1005 + 9.0*x1006 + 31.0*x1007 + 4.0*x1008 + 10.0*x1009 + 0.0*x1010)
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x0102 + 1.0*x0103 + 1.0*x0104 + 1.0*x0105 + 1.0*x0106 + 1.0*x0107 + 1.0*x0108 + 1.0*x0109 + 1.0*x0110 + 1.0*y01) <= 1.0
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x0201 + 1.0*x0203 + 1.0*x0204 + 1.0*x0205 + 1.0*x0206 + 1.0*x0207 + 1.0*x0208 + 1.0*x0209 + 1.0*x0210 + 1.0*y02) <= 1.0
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x0301 + 1.0*x0302 + 1.0*x0304 + 1.0*x0305 + 1.0*x0306 + 1.0*x0307 + 1.0*x0308 + 1.0*x0309 + 1.0*x0310 + 1.0*y03) <= 1.0
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x0401 + 1.0*x0402 + 1.0*x0403 + 1.0*x0405 + 1.0*x0406 + 1.0*x0407 + 1.0*x0408 + 1.0*x0409 + 1.0*x0410 + 1.0*y04) <= 1.0
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x0501 + 1.0*x0502 + 1.0*x0503 + 1.0*x0504 + 1.0*x0506 + 1.0*x0507 + 1.0*x0508 + 1.0*x0509 + 1.0*x0510 + 1.0*y05) <= 1.0
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x0601 + 1.0*x0602 + 1.0*x0603 + 1.0*x0604 + 1.0*x0605 + 1.0*x0607 + 1.0*x0608 + 1.0*x0609 + 1.0*x0610 + 1.0*y06) <= 1.0
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x0701 + 1.0*x0702 + 1.0*x0703 + 1.0*x0704 + 1.0*x0705 + 1.0*x0706 + 1.0*x0708 + 1.0*x0709 + 1.0*x0710 + 1.0*y07) <= 1.0
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x0801 + 1.0*x0802 + 1.0*x0803 + 1.0*x0804 + 1.0*x0805 + 1.0*x0806 + 1.0*x0807 + 1.0*x0809 + 1.0*x0810 + 1.0*y08) <= 1.0
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x0901 + 1.0*x0902 + 1.0*x0903 + 1.0*x0904 + 1.0*x0905 + 1.0*x0906 + 1.0*x0907 + 1.0*x0908 + 1.0*x0910 + 1.0*y09) <= 1.0
IloRange  : 1.0 <= (1.0*x1001 + 1.0*x1002 + 1.0*x1003 + 1.0*x1004 + 1.0*x1005 + 1.0*x1006 + 1.0*x1007 + 1.0*x1008 + 1.0*x1009 + 1.0*y10) <= 1.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0102 - 1.0*y02) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0103 - 1.0*y03) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0104 - 1.0*y04) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0105 - 1.0*y05) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0106 - 1.0*y06) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0107 - 1.0*y07) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0108 - 1.0*y08) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0109 - 1.0*y09) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0110 - 1.0*y10) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x0201) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0203 - 1.0*y03) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0204 - 1.0*y04) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0205 - 1.0*y05) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0206 - 1.0*y06) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0207 - 1.0*y07) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0208 - 1.0*y08) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0209 - 1.0*y09) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0210 - 1.0*y10) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x0301) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y02 + 1.0*x0302) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0304 - 1.0*y04) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0305 - 1.0*y05) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0306 - 1.0*y06) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0307 - 1.0*y07) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0308 - 1.0*y08) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0309 - 1.0*y09) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0310 - 1.0*y10) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x0401) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y02 + 1.0*x0402) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y03 + 1.0*x0403) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0405 - 1.0*y05) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0406 - 1.0*y06) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0407 - 1.0*y07) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0408 - 1.0*y08) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0409 - 1.0*y09) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0410 - 1.0*y10) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x0501) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y02 + 1.0*x0502) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y03 + 1.0*x0503) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y04 + 1.0*x0504) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0506 - 1.0*y06) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0507 - 1.0*y07) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0508 - 1.0*y08) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0509 - 1.0*y09) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0510 - 1.0*y10) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x0601) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y02 + 1.0*x0602) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y03 + 1.0*x0603) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y04 + 1.0*x0604) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y05 + 1.0*x0605) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0607 - 1.0*y07) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0608 - 1.0*y08) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0609 - 1.0*y09) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0610 - 1.0*y10) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x0701) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y02 + 1.0*x0702) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y03 + 1.0*x0703) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y04 + 1.0*x0704) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y05 + 1.0*x0705) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y06 + 1.0*x0706) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0708 - 1.0*y08) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0709 - 1.0*y09) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0710 - 1.0*y10) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x0801) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y02 + 1.0*x0802) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y03 + 1.0*x0803) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y04 + 1.0*x0804) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y05 + 1.0*x0805) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y06 + 1.0*x0806) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y07 + 1.0*x0807) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0809 - 1.0*y09) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0810 - 1.0*y10) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x0901) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y02 + 1.0*x0902) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y03 + 1.0*x0903) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y04 + 1.0*x0904) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y05 + 1.0*x0905) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y06 + 1.0*x0906) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y07 + 1.0*x0907) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y08 + 1.0*x0908) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0910 - 1.0*y10) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x1001) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y02 + 1.0*x1002) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y03 + 1.0*x1003) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y04 + 1.0*x1004) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y05 + 1.0*x1005) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y06 + 1.0*x1006) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y07 + 1.0*x1007) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y08 + 1.0*x1008) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-1.0*y09 + 1.0*x1009) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y01 + 1.0*x0101) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y02 + 1.0*x0202) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y03 + 1.0*x0303) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y04 + 1.0*x0404) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y05 + 1.0*x0505) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y06 + 1.0*x0606) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y07 + 1.0*x0707) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y08 + 1.0*x0808) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y09 + 1.0*x0909) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 0.0 <= (-1.0*y10 + 1.0*x1010) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (-2.0*y01 + 1.0*x0201 + 1.0*x0301 + 1.0*x0401 + 1.0*x0501 + 1.0*x0601 + 1.0*x0701 + 1.0*x0801 + 1.0*x0901 + 1.0*x1001 + 1.0*x0101) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0102 - 2.0*y02 + 1.0*x0302 + 1.0*x0402 + 1.0*x0502 + 1.0*x0602 + 1.0*x0702 + 1.0*x0802 + 1.0*x0902 + 1.0*x1002 + 1.0*x0202) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0103 + 1.0*x0203 - 4.0*y03 + 1.0*x0403 + 1.0*x0503 + 1.0*x0603 + 1.0*x0703 + 1.0*x0803 + 1.0*x0903 + 1.0*x1003 + 1.0*x0303) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0104 + 1.0*x0204 + 1.0*x0304 - 4.0*y04 + 1.0*x0504 + 1.0*x0604 + 1.0*x0704 + 1.0*x0804 + 1.0*x0904 + 1.0*x1004 + 1.0*x0404) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0105 + 1.0*x0205 + 1.0*x0305 + 1.0*x0405 - 4.0*y05 + 1.0*x0605 + 1.0*x0705 + 1.0*x0805 + 1.0*x0905 + 1.0*x1005 + 1.0*x0505) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0106 + 1.0*x0206 + 1.0*x0306 + 1.0*x0406 + 1.0*x0506 - 5.0*y06 + 1.0*x0706 + 1.0*x0806 + 1.0*x0906 + 1.0*x1006 + 1.0*x0606) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0107 + 1.0*x0207 + 1.0*x0307 + 1.0*x0407 + 1.0*x0507 + 1.0*x0607 - 5.0*y07 + 1.0*x0807 + 1.0*x0907 + 1.0*x1007 + 1.0*x0707) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0108 + 1.0*x0208 + 1.0*x0308 + 1.0*x0408 + 1.0*x0508 + 1.0*x0608 + 1.0*x0708 - 5.0*y08 + 1.0*x0908 + 1.0*x1008 + 1.0*x0808) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0109 + 1.0*x0209 + 1.0*x0309 + 1.0*x0409 + 1.0*x0509 + 1.0*x0609 + 1.0*x0709 + 1.0*x0809 - 5.0*y09 + 1.0*x1009 + 1.0*x0909) <= 0.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x0110 + 1.0*x0210 + 1.0*x0310 + 1.0*x0410 + 1.0*x0510 + 1.0*x0610 + 1.0*x0710 + 1.0*x0810 + 1.0*x0910 - 5.0*y10 + 1.0*x1010) <= 0.0
IloRange  : 619.0 <= (36.0*x0102 + 296.0*x0103 + 24.0*x0104 + 188.0*x0105 + 288.0*x0106 + 60.0*x0107 + 384.0*x0108 + 304.0*x0109 + 132.0*x0110 + 58.0*y01 + 380.0*x0201 + 276.0*x0203 + 12.0*x0204 + 336.0*x0205 + 156.0*x0206 + 28.0*x0207 + 12.0*x0208 + 132.0*x0209 + 4.0*x0210 + 58.0*y02 + 240.0*x0301 + 196.0*x0302 + 324.0*x0304 + 172.0*x0305 + 64.0*x0306 + 44.0*x0307 + 60.0*x0308 + 92.0*x0309 + 36.0*x0310 + 116.0*y03 + 60.0*x0401 + 308.0*x0402 + 8.0*x0403 + 268.0*x0405 + 88.0*x0406 + 372.0*x0407 + 288.0*x0408 + 388.0*x0409 + 336.0*x0410 + 116.0*y04 + 268.0*x0501 + 116.0*x0502 + 248.0*x0503 + 256.0*x0504 + 224.0*x0506 + 348.0*x0507 + 116.0*x0508 + 48.0*x0509 + 368.0*x0510 + 116.0*y05 + 52.0*x0601 + 372.0*x0602 + 88.0*x0603 + 100.0*x0604 + 240.0*x0605 + 128.0*x0607 + 168.0*x0608 + 244.0*x0609 + 16.0*x0610 + 145.0*y06 + 28.0*x0701 + 96.0*x0702 + 48.0*x0703 + 344.0*x0704 + 108.0*x0705 + 208.0*x0706 + 284.0*x0708 + 48.0*x0709 + 224.0*x0710 + 145.0*y07 + 388.0*x0801 + 276.0*x0802 + 180.0*x0803 + 40.0*x0804 + 340.0*x0805 + 100.0*x0806 + 288.0*x0807 + 152.0*x0809 + 312.0*x0810 + 145.0*y08 + 92.0*x0901 + 388.0*x0902 + 48.0*x0903 + 324.0*x0904 + 224.0*x0905 + 396.0*x0906 + 284.0*x0907 + 284.0*x0908 + 140.0*x0910 + 145.0*y09 + 224.0*x1001 + 8.0*x1002 + 240.0*x1003 + 308.0*x1004 + 384.0*x1005 + 36.0*x1006 + 124.0*x1007 + 16.0*x1008 + 40.0*x1009 + 145.0*y10) <= 619.0
IloRange  : -infinity <= (2.0*y01 + 2.0*y02 + 4.0*y03 + 4.0*y04 + 4.0*y05 + 5.0*y06 + 5.0*y07 + 5.0*y08 + 5.0*y09 + 5.0*y10) <= 14.0

}
```

List of X variables that were 1:

```
result = {ArrayList@1078}  size = 6
 0 = {CpxNumVar@1080} "x0101"
 1 = {CpxNumVar@1081} "x0208"
 2 = {CpxNumVar@1082} "x0508"
 3 = {CpxNumVar@1083} "x0601"
 4 = {CpxNumVar@1084} "x0808"
 5 = {CpxNumVar@1085} "x1008"
```

List of Y variables that were 1

```
result = {ArrayList@1098}  size = 2
 0 = {CpxNumVar@1100} "y01"
 1 = {CpxNumVar@1101} "y08"
```

There was supposed to be 10 variables of X with value 1,
Notice that the 3rd constraint is not met, as there is no x03** nor y03 with value 1.

I'm solving multiple problems with the same constraints but different objectives. So i just manipulate the objective maintaining the constraints. Sometimes I need two add a constraint or to and I do so like this:

Manipulating the objective:

```
this.model.getObjective().setExpr(expr);
```

And the constraints as such^

```
IloRange equality = this.model.eq(expr,value);
IloRange constraint = this.model.le(expr,value);
this.model.add(equality);
this.model.add(constraint);
while(this.model.solve()){
    //do stuff with solution
    this.model.remove(constraint);
    constraint = this.model.le(expr,newValue);
    this.model.add(constraint);
}
```

This was working for the starting LPs.

This particular LP, the solution was not coming up as expected, as the data that I'm using, I know what is supposed to happen.

I've debugged and after the solve, I check what happens in the model and to the vars and what not.
There are a lot of IloRange that are not satisfied. Why could this be the case? Is there any known bug of the CPLEX Java API?

Debugging the decompiled classes of the cplex.jar I get that the status was Optimal, so CPLEX thinks he found an optimal value.

Additional information:

I'm using IDEA 14.1.2 community version.
To compile the code I'm using Java 8 update 45 64 bit architecture.
Using integrated maven with no additional plugins.
The cplex.jar was taken from an installation done in 64-bit linux.
To run the program I'm using Java 8 update 31 of 32 bit architecture, since the only cplex1260.dll that I could get my hands on is 32 bit.
My OS is: Windows 7 64 bit

EDIT:

I'm beggining to think that there is something wrong with my DLL. Where can I find another?

EDIT2 (on linux now):

I've managed to solve this particular LP. But now other LPs are getting the same symptoms:

I have the following code:

```
IloRange constraint = this.model.addLe(expr, value);
this.model.solve();
//use solution for something
this.model.remove(constraint);
```

And I'm iterating the value such that it gets smaller and smaller. So, I don't need to remove the constraint, just keep adding them. So I changed the code to:

```
this.plbo.getModel().addLe(expr, value);
this.plbo.getModel().solve();
//use solution for something
```

And surprise, surprise, it took him two more iterations to fail solving a LP.

I've also tried with:

```
this.constraint.setUB(newUB);
this.model.solve();
//use solution for something
```

Where `constraint` is an `IloRange` that is initialized with:

```
this.constraint = this.model.addLe(expr,Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

The same results as the first try with only one constraint happens, which is to be expected.

Any ideas?

EDIT3:

I'm starting to think that it has something to do with CPLEX Parameters and not the libs. The default parameters are different in the linux libs, hence the difference.

Can anyone tell me about parameters that I can change in order to make the solution satisfy all the constraints?

EDIT4:

I've just compared the output of this code ran on windows vs the one ran on linux (each one with it's set of libs for windows (dll) and linux):

```
        for(Field field : IloCplex.IntParam.class.getDeclaredFields()){
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " " + this.model.getParam((IloCplex.IntParam)field.get(this)));
        }
        for(Field field : IloCplex.BooleanParam.class.getDeclaredFields()){
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " " + this.model.getParam((IloCplex.BooleanParam)field.get(this)));
        }
        for(Field field : IloCplex.DoubleParam.class.getDeclaredFields()){
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " " + this.model.getParam((IloCplex.DoubleParam)field.get(this)));
        }
        for(Field field : IloCplex.StringParam.class.getDeclaredFields()){
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " " + this.model.getParam((IloCplex.StringParam)field.get(this)));
        }
        for(Field field : IloCplex.LongParam.class.getDeclaredFields()){
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " " + this.model.getParam((IloCplex.LongParam)field.get(this)));
        }
```

To check the defined value of the params. They were ALL the same...

I'm now, once again, blaming the libs on this one. What else can I do?

EDIT5:

After using export model, I present to you the output of the output from the Interactive Optimizer is the following:

```
Variable Name           Solution Value
x0210                         1.000000
x0310                         1.000000
x0509                         1.000000
x0610                         1.000000
x0701                         1.000000
x0804                         1.000000
y01                           1.000000
y04                           1.000000
y09                           1.000000
y10                           1.000000
x0101                         1.000000
x0404                         1.000000
x0909                         1.000000
x1010                         1.000000
```

But in my project, the Xs and Ys are as follow:

```
result = {ArrayList@1230}  size = 8
 0 = {CpxNumVar@1233} "x0101"
 1 = {CpxNumVar@1234} "x0210"
 2 = {CpxNumVar@1235} "x0310"
 3 = {CpxNumVar@1236} "x0404"
 4 = {CpxNumVar@1237} "x0610"
 5 = {CpxNumVar@1238} "x0701"
 6 = {CpxNumVar@1239} "x0804"
 7 = {CpxNumVar@1240} "x1010"

result = {ArrayList@1252}  size = 3
 0 = {CpxNumVar@1254} "y01"
 1 = {CpxNumVar@1255} "y04"
 2 = {CpxNumVar@1256} "y10"
```

I used the following code to return the Xs and the Ys:

```
public List<IloIntVar> getXs() throws IloException {
    List<IloIntVar> vars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.dim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.dim; j++) {
            if (this.model.getValue(this.xVars[i][j]) == 1) {
                vars.add(this.xVars[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return vars;
}

public List<IloIntVar> getYs() throws IloException {
    List<IloIntVar> vars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.dim; i++) {
        if (this.model.getValue(this.yVars[i]) == 1) {
            vars.add(this.yVars[i]);
        }
    }
    return vars;
}
```

EDIT6:

The problem was that I was making this:

```
(int) (this.model.getValue(var))
```

which I turned into

```
(int) (this.model.getValue(var)+0.5)
```

This way, it rounds the int correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My standard approach for these sorts of issues is to get CPLEX to dump out the internal model as an LP file and check that it makes sense and matches what you were expecting. Then maybe try solving the LP file in the standalone CPLEX, and check the answers. I am guessing that there is a mistake somewhere and that the model inside CPLEX is different from what you think. Once you know where the difference lies, you can check your code more carefully and maybe find the error. Eventually you may prove that it is a problem in the Java interface, but most likely is an error in your own code.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and thank you for your advice. Even though, in this case, I solved the LP with the last constraint being <= 41.
Did something with the solution (it was correct and satisfied all constraints) and then changed the restriction to <= 14, like I said in the question. The following solve did not satisfy all of the constraints. There were constrains that were not touched that were not satisfied.

Comment: Also: I've already solved the same PLs using the standalone CPLEX. I used Java to write to a file and invoke bash commands to run CPLEX, read the file, solve write outputs and then I had to read the outputs. With the Java API this would be much faster, which is what I'm trying to accomplish now.

Comment: I've tried with other DLLs, in this case I tried to use the libs in the linux installation while running the program in that same linux. This LP was solved correctly :). Alas, in some other LP, the same problem started to happen, even with the linux libs. I'm starting to believe that this is indeed a problem in the Java iplementation of Cplex.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment. Did you generate an LP file by hand (using java) to feed to Cplex, or did you build the model using the java API for cplex and generate the LP file using cplex.exportModel()

Comment: "Did you generate an LP file by hand (using java) to feed to Cplex"

This one. This was my first approach to the problem at hand. The model is fine. The same model runs differently on windows and on linux. They use different libs that may have different default configurations. I just don't know how to configure them correctly.

Comment: First, cplex *will not* give you a solution that does not satisfy the constraints (to within the tolerances),  whatever the values of the parameters,  whether on Windows or Linux, 32 or 64 bit,  whatever. You may get different answers, but they should all be equivalent and satisfy all the constraints. There are too many people who use CPLEX on a daily basis and without errors for me to believe that your errors are due to bugs inside cplex. Dump your model from cplex using exportModel()  and check it. Whatever you think or say,  I would bet large sums of money on there being a mistake.

Comment: If you could stop being condescending and actually read my question you would realize that there can't be any mistake in the model. Anyway, I did as you said and the exportModel() is quite handy. Now the problem persists. Read my next EDIT5 as I can't type everything in a comment.

Comment: If you would be so kind as to check the EDIT5 I just posted, I would be thankfull.

Comment: So which is correct,  the solution from the interactive optimiser or the one from your project? I will bet that the solution from the interactive optimiser satisfies all the constraints in the LP file you used. Do the values from your project satisfy the constraints in the exported LP file? Do the values from the standalone optimiser fit your intended model? Also, having read everything you have written multiple times I fail to understand why you believe that there cannot be any mistakes in your model. Print the variable values rather than test if equal to 1.

Comment: The one from the interactive optimiser satisfies all the constraints in the LP file used. The values from the standalone fit my intended model, but this I already knew.
Recall this EDIT:
"EDIT2 (on linux now):
I've managed to solve this particular LP. But now other LPs are getting the same symptoms:"
This means, that with no changes in the code, no changes in the model, when I packed the jar and ran it in linux, the solution was correct, and satisfied all constraints. Meanwhile, using the same jar in Windows resulted in the problem described. So the model was not the problem.

Comment: So, I did as you said and checked the value for all the variables and got this: 0.9999999999999998 for one of the ones that were missing. Like I said, there was no error in the model :)
Alas, precision errors were my bane in this problem. Thank you for your help. Please do tell me: How can variables of the type `IloIntVar` that were initialized with `this.model.boolVar("x");` get such precision errors? I think the answer is simply that bool is just a wrapper for doubles and the bool is used when exporting the model, since they came out as binaries.

Comment: I had something like this:
`(int) this.model.getValue(var)` which was coming up as 0, obviously...
Once again, thanks for insisting and making me check the value of all the variables

Comment: Apologies for not spotting this issue before. You are correct in thinking that "integer" or boolean variables are modelled internally as doubles or similar. The declaration just forces the solver to make them integer valued at some level of tolerance. Need to be careful always with floating point precision,  even with integers!